# 'cannot find -lgcc_s' error when giving toolchain file for Power-PC to CMAKE setup

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, cross-compiling, powerpc

I am facing some strange issue in cmake while trying to do the cross compilation build. For native build it is working as per expectation:

**Case 1:**  toolchain file is given in include() of CMakelists.txt file.

For Power-PC build, when I give the toolchain file in following way in the CMakelists.txt file :

```
if(ARM)
include(config/toolchain_la9.cmake)
elseif(POWER-PC)
include(config/toolchain_lppc.cmake)
endif()
```

everything is working fine and I am able to get all generated executable and binaries with these following compiler and linker flags

**/opt/freescale-2010.09/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc   -mdouble-float
 -msoft-float   -static-libgcc -lpthread -lm -lrt**

**Case 2:** toolchain file is given with cmake -D command.

Again when I commented the case 1 code snippet and try to give the same file as

**cmake PATH_TO_CMAKE_DIRECTORY -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/one/toolchain_files/toolchain_lppc.cmake**

This time I am not able to cross compile the source code.

with the following error:

> /opt/freescale-2010.09/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../powerpc-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lgcc_

s

**Case 3:**   With Cmake-gui using 'specify toolchain file for cross-compiling' option

[image]

When I give the same file as input to this option. Again I am getting the same issue:

> /opt/freescale-2010.09/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../powerpc-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lgcc_s

1. The error clearly indicates that the libgcc_s is not present under specified toolchain path. But if it is not present how it is working in case 1.
2. How I am getting -static-libgcc flag in case 1, do I need to give it explicitly in toolchain file in 2nd and 3rd case.
3. Even in toolchain file if I am using CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS for adding -static-libgcc in 2nd and 3rd case, it is still showing same errors.

I am new in cmake. though it seems very useful to me but here I am stuck.

The toolchain file content is as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/freescale-2010.09/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc )
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/freescale-2010.09/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-g++)
set(CMAKE_STRIP /opt/freescale-2010.09/bin/powerpc-linux-gnu-strip)

set(CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "/opt/freescale-2010.09/lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnu/4.5.1/")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mdouble-float -msoft-float")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mdouble-float -msoft-float")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER) 
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY) 
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY) 
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

Comment: "toolchain file is given in include()" - This is NOT how toolchain should be used. The only correct use is specifying toolchain in `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable (either via cmake parameters or in the `CMakeLists.txt` before the `project()` call). Otherwise it is very possible to mix toolchain settings with host-related ones. If you have errors with your toolchain, you need to show us that toolchain (add its code into the question post).

Comment: I have updated the comment with the CMake toolchain file I am using. The thing is within the toolchain directory there is no such library(libgcc_s) present, but by using the simple Makefile script  I am able to build the cross-compiled on Power-PC with same toolchain directory.

Comment: Well, it is time to add more description about the error you got: is it emitted when CMake checks the compiler or when it compiles your executable? If the former, then `CMakeLists.txt` with two lines(`cmake_minimum_required()` and `project()` calls) should reproduce the problem (check that!). If the latter, then your project itself is involved into the problem, so we need to see your `CMakeLists.txt` (in form of [mcve]) for being able to help you. Note, that your toolchain sets `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` **incorrectly**: the *CACHE* variable should be set instead.